# An elementary question worth asking

Tags: atoms, kinetic-theory-of-gases

We all know that an atom starts moving faster when it's heated.But actually atom is not some new thing itself in the sense that it is just a bunch of electrons and protons. So, I think that same happens to the electrons or protons within. What does?

Comment: Electrons and protons don't move. Besides, there are discrete quantum states, and the first excited state of most atoms is already pretty high. Until you reach that temperature, **nothing** changes inside the atom.

Comment: I am just a ninth grader so it would be better if you can make it simpler.